# Adding the date of adding todo-note

Tags: external-files

As is -I suspect- usual is that while writing documents sometimes one skips writing certain parts for a cornucopia of reasons. For me that is usually because I am too lazy at the moment. In an case, then I have the following command to make a todo-note (can look better, I know):

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{ \vspace{5 mm} \par
\noindent \framebox{
\begin{minipage}
[c]{0.94 \textwidth}
\tt #1 \flushright  TODO
\end{minipage}
}
\vspace{5 mm} \par
}
```

I have obtained this some time ago from [here](http://atchieu.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/all-the-latex-macros-and-packages-that-you-will-ever-need-in-one-file/). My question is how I add the date of adding the todo-note? One can assume that at least I compile the file on the same day as I added the todo-note, so to me, this sounds like the LaTeX process should store this in an auxiliary file (preferable one that already exists). How do I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier simply to add the date manually when writing the note?

Comment: I suppose it is easy to do that, but the technique in itself might be useful in other cases as well :-).

Comment: This does not answer your question, but you should have a look at [the `todonotes` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes).

Comment: @PeterGrill I know that package, but it has too many features while what I need is really simple.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen: Ok.  If you want to save the date when a `\todo` is _first_ added to a file, you will also need to provide a unique name for _each_ `\todo` in case you have more than one in a file.

Comment: How would your `.aux` file idea work?  Each note would need to create its own `.aux` file on the first (subsequent) latex run, and which would then never be overwritten by subsequent latex runs?  Otherwise, whenever you re-latex your file, the 'date' information would get re-written.

Comment: @jon You don't have to use the main `.aux` file, but use another one that is specific to that feature. Other packages do the same. This new helper file would never be overwritten, but only appended to. (Hm, I don't know wether the TeX engine can append to a file.)

Comment: @mafp -- of course.  In fact, you *can't* use the main `.aux` file since it needs to be re-generated each run. (I should have been clear I meant an aux-like file.)  If appending to an aux-like file is possible, then you're right only one would be needed; I assumed that it was not possible, and that you'd need to create a different/new file for each todo note that is also somehow 'locked' on creation.  I've never tried to do anything like that, but it should be possible as indexing facilities can do something like that (e.g., the 'noautomatic' option of `imakeidx`).

Comment: As the other comments indicate, this really doesn't seem to make sense as it stands! We need some idea of how things should work.