# Date of creation of todo

Tags: documentation, date

I am trying to get the date of creation of the todo item.
is it possible to add the todo item at compile time.

I did have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87226/adding-the-date-of-adding-todo-note).. But i was wondering if it is possible to do with the `due` keyword.

Atleast that's the best case scenario from this [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf).

```
%% TODONOTES
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % TO DISABLE

\newcommand{\rnline}[1]{\todo[author=TANDEM,size=\small,inline,color=green!40,due=\today]{#1}}
\newcommand{\rn}[1]{\todo[color=blue!40]{#1}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The  best case scenario defines, that  the todo should be done today. When you translate the document the next day, the date will be adapted. But the creation date should keep the (first) creation date, That's something complete different.

Comment: I agree with you. Everytime I compile it, the date changes.. and I was wondering if there is a way LaTeX can create a date of creating file in some format which need not be changed unless specified by the user.. maybe very specific question.. any hints in this direction would be helpful

Comment: What if you have `\todo`'s from different days? Wouldn't it be safer simply put date manually to each of them?

Comment: I agree with having different dates... that's the reason i want a table which it can lookup before compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can not use `\today` or current date of the day or such commands
for adding the creation date for the todo comments. It is obvious by every 
compile the date will change and we will lose the former creation time (or due time).
So maybe it is the best to write the time manually in your own defined template. I hope this helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\newif\ifallowtodo

\begin{document}

\listoftodos
\allowtodotrue   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla
\ifallowtodo \todo{Plain todonotes.\footnotesize{$\rightarrow$ \textit{Due Mar 22 '17}}} \else \fi
urna. Maecenas interdum nunc in augue. Mauris quis massa in ante
tincidunt mollis. Proin imperdiet. Donec porttitor pede id est. Sed
in ante. Integer id arcu. Nam lectus nisl, posuere sit amet,
imperdiet ut, tristique ac, lorem. In erat. In commodo enim.
\ifallowtodo \todo[color=blue!40]{Todonote with a different color. \footnotesize{$\rightarrow$ \textit{Due Sep 17 '16}}} \else \fi
Phasellus libero ipsum, tempor a, pharetra consequat, pellentesque
sit amet, sem. Praesent ut augue luctus elit adipiscing ultricies.
Vestibulum suscipit cursus leo. Nullam molestie justo.
\end{document}
```

`\allowtodotrue` is just a flag for `\ifallowtodo` to check whether we want
the todo mode or full pdf without todo. You can get rid of that if it is not
necessary.
[image]

Comment: I did think of using this idea.. but i don't like the idea of writing dates manually.

Comment: I suggest some kind of snippet for this, either through your editor or a dedicated textexpansionsoftware, like `aText`, `TextExpander` or simular. I have it set up so that depending on which software I am currently in, it will output the current date whenever I write `@today`, and it will replace it immidiently when I use a texteditor to `2016-09-12`, and when I am in a internet browser it will expand to `mandag 12. september 2016`. I've also set up a few variations, like `@yesterday`, `@nextmonday``@day+14` etc.